# How to send these datas made through dynamic view to another activity (ListView probably)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listview

So, I have done exactly what's on this video: http://android-er.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/add-and-remove-view-dynamically.html

Now, i'd like to get these names I added and send to another activity when I click the "Next" button (it's not on the video, btw). These names should be displayed like in a list view.

To exemplify it better: think of it as a Bowling software. The add/remove view on the video would be the add/remove players from the game. Once you add everyone you want to, you would click the "Next" button and then it would start another activity with the names you have just added and their scores, etc. I think I could use SQLite to store those names, but since it lasts for one game only, I thought using putExtra or whatever, would be the best way. But I have never tried this before, so I don't know how to send this data to a ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an arraylist in your first activity and add your data to it

```
 ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
 arrayList.add("data");
 arrayList.add("anotherdata");
```

Send data by Intent putExtra

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("arrayList", (ArrayList<String>) arrayList);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your secondActivity get the data like

```
 ArrayList<String> mylist=getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("arrayList");
```

Set your arraylist to your listview like following using adapter

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
     new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mylist);
  listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. It looks like it works, but unfortunately I can't test it right now. Should I set this as a correct answer already?

Comment: I don't know how many strings are gonna be added by the user though. So would it work anyways?

Comment: Doesnt matter the number of data. It will always work @YagoKhairalla

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to a new `Activity` by using a `Bundle`. It works like this:

First create a new `Bundle` and put the data you want to send into that...

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name1", "John");
bundle.putString("name2", "Larry");
bundle.putString("name3", "Cindy");
```

Then create a new `Intent` and attach the `Bundle` to it. Then start your new `Activity` using the `Intent` you just created...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourSecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then when the new `Activity` starts up, in the `onCreate()` method you can extract the data from the `Bundle` like this...

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String name1 = bundle.getString("name1");
String name2 = bundle.getString("name2");
String name3 = bundle.getString("name3");
```

Then if you wanted to put those names in a `ListView` you could do something like this:

Put the names in an `ArrayList`...

```
ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
nameList.add(name1);
nameList.add(name2);
nameList.add(name3);
```

Then inflate your view and populate your `ListView` with the `ArrayList`...

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_activity_layout, container, false);
ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_listview);
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(view.getContext(), R.layout.your_list_item_layout, nameList);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: That's interesting as well. I'll try both solutions when i'm able to. Thanks :)